# Call Oracle stored procedure from PHP

Tags: php, oracle

I am trying to execute and get data from my procedure:

Here is the way my procedure is defined:

```sql
create or replace PROCEDURE SP_GET_MY_DATA(
         IN_POP VARCHAR2,
         IN_SEG VARCHAR2,
         IN_DUR VARCHAR2, 
         IN_VIEW INTEGER, 
         IN_PAGE INTEGER, 
         VIEW_DATA_CUR OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) AS ...
```

Here is my PHP code to execute and get data from procedure:

```
$db = "(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = JXYX.com)(PORT = 1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=DHSJKS)))";
$conn = ocilogon("XXXXXX","XXXXXXXX",$db);          

$sql = 'BEGIN SP_GET_MY_DATA(:POP, :SEG, :DUR, :VIEW, :PAGE, :OUTPUT_CUR); END;';            

$stmt = oci_parse($conn,$sql);                     
oci_bind_by_name($stmt,':POP',$pop);           
oci_bind_by_name($stmt,':SEG',$seg);           
oci_bind_by_name($stmt,':DUR',$dur);           
oci_bind_by_name($stmt,':VIEW',$view);           
oci_bind_by_name($stmt,':PAGE',$page);           
$OUTPUT_CUR = oci_new_cursor($conn);
oci_bind_by_name($stmt,":OUTPUT_CUR", $OUTPUT_CUR, -1, OCI_B_CURSOR);                   
oci_execute($stmt, OCI_DEFAULT); 

while ($data = oci_fetch_assoc($OUTPUT_CUR)) {
    print_r($data);
}
```

But in doing so I am getting this error:

> oci_fetch_assoc(): ORA-24374: define not done before fetch or execute and fetch".

I am not able to figure out what I'm missing. Can you help?

Comment: after executing `$stmt`, you must execute `$OUTOUT_CUR` as well

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To work with a cursor in PHP three additional steps are required, as compared to accessing rows directly from a `SELECT` statement.

- The first step is preparing a cursor resource in PHP using the `oci_new_cursor()` function, which you then use to bind to the appropriate parameter.
- The second step is to add a parameter on `oci_bind_by_name()` function
- The third step, after you have executed the usual SQL statement, is calling `oci_execute()` on the cursor resource.

The code:

```
//Connection does not change
$db = "(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = JXYX.com)(PORT = 1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=DHSJKS)))";
$conn = ocilogon("XXXXXX","XXXXXXXX",$db);          

//Request does not change
$sql = 'BEGIN SP_GET_MY_DATA(:POP, :SEG, :DUR, :VIEW, :PAGE, :OUTPUT_CUR); END;';            

//Statement does not change
$stmt = oci_parse($conn,$sql);                     
oci_bind_by_name($stmt,':POP',$pop);           
oci_bind_by_name($stmt,':SEG',$seg);           
oci_bind_by_name($stmt,':DUR',$dur);           
oci_bind_by_name($stmt,':VIEW',$view);           
oci_bind_by_name($stmt,':PAGE',$page);    

//But BEFORE statement, Create your cursor
$cursor = oci_new_cursor($conn)

// On your code add the latest parameter to bind the cursor resource to the Oracle argument
oci_bind_by_name($stmt,":OUTPUT_CUR", $cursor,-1,OCI_B_CURSOR);

// Execute the statement as in your first try
oci_execute($stmt);

// and now, execute the cursor
oci_execute($cursor);

// Use OCIFetchinto in the same way as you would with SELECT
while ($data = oci_fetch_assoc($cursor, OCI_RETURN_LOBS )) {
    print_r($data);
}
```

I'm not very fluent with Oracle (and english) so you should read [this tutorial](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/fuecks-sps-095636.html). There is an interesting example, look at the *Stored Procedures and Reference Cursors* chapter!

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

This example is based in [Oracle Documentation](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/fuecks-sps-095636.html)

```
// Define MYDB connection string as described in tnsnames.ora
define("MYDB","(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = JXYX.com)(PORT = 1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=DHSJKS)))");
// Connect to database
$conn = oci_connect("XXXXXX","XXXXXXXX",MYDB);  
// Through error if not connected 
if (!$conn) {
    $e = oci_error();
    trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
}  
// Bind the your input and output parameters to PHP variables                
$stmt = oci_parse($conn,'BEGIN SP_GET_MY_DATA(:POP, :SEG, :DUR, :VIEW, :PAGE, :OUTPUT_CUR); END;');                     
oci_bind_by_name($stmt,':POP',$pop);           
oci_bind_by_name($stmt,':SEG',$seg);           
oci_bind_by_name($stmt,':DUR',$dur);           
oci_bind_by_name($stmt,':VIEW',$view);           
oci_bind_by_name($stmt,':PAGE',$page);  
// Declare your cursor         
$OUTPUT_CUR = oci_new_cursor($conn);
oci_bind_by_name($stmt,":OUTPUT_CUR", $OUTPUT_CUR, -1, OCI_B_CURSOR);    
// Execute statement               
oci_execute($stmt); 
// Execute the cursor
oci_execute($OUTPUT_CUR);
// Fetch results
while ($data = oci_fetch_assoc($OUTPUT_CUR)) {
    print_r($data);
}
```