# Multiple queries with oracle

Tags: php, oracle

I would like to execute two queries in ORACLE version 11g at the same time and take care that if one or both queries fails must return both tables to the previous state.

In my case I need to make an update and later and insert on another table, so the queries will be like these approximately:

```
$query="UPDATE table1 SET attr1 = ? WHERE whatever";
$stmt = $this->oracleDB->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindValue(1, $attr1, "string");
$stmt->execute();

$query="INSERT INTO table2 (attr2) VALUES (?)";
$stmt = $this->oracleDB->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindValue(1, $attr2, "string");
$stmt->execute();
```

Also I'm using the binding system to send the variables more safety. Not sure If can affect the answer.

I'm not sure if the procedure is the answer and if it's the answer, how will looks like in this example the procedure?

Thank you very much.

Comment: whats the relationship between the first and the second query?

Comment: If you have access to make changes to the database, you could put both queries in a stored procedure where any fail state would rollback any successful changes.

Comment: This is standard transactions. Ensure autocommit is off, do you DML. on any exception do a rollback.

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41506335/call-oracle-stored-procedure-from-php

Comment: Can anyone of you write how will looks the call to the procedure and the code I should add to the procedure on the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an anonymous PL/SQL block like to run multiple statements:

```
$query=" BEGIN UPDATE table1 SET attr1 = ? WHERE whatever;
          INSERT INTO table2 (attr2) VALUES (?);END; ";
$stmt = $this->oracleDB->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindValue(1, $attr1, "string");
$stmt->bindValue(2, $attr2, "string");
$stmt->execute();
```

Probably a stored procedure is cleaner.

Comment: I guess the second prepare($query) is not necessary.

Comment: Excuse me again but... is not necessary to add a SAVEPOINT nameSavePoint; and the EXCEPTION code to roll_back to the save_point? I never used this but in this page appears this concept: 
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/sqloperations.htm#BABGAAIG

In your example if the insert fails can undo the previous update?

Comment: I would assume the oracleDB object has functions for starting/ending a transaction.