# PHP/OCI - Unable to get results from Oracle procedure within a temporary table

Tags: php, oracle, oracle-call-interface

I am attempting to do two things using the PHP OCI Oracle functions:

1. Run a package procedure within an Oracle database.
2. Once the package has ran, query a temporary table to get the results of the procedure's operation.

**I am able to do this successfully using the SQL Developer software provided from Oracle. My query is extremely basic and can been seen below:**

```
BEGIN
    PKG_KTY_SEARCH.PR_PRICE_LIST();
END;
/
SELECT * FROM kty_web.KTY_PROD_PRICE_TEMP;
```

This code above works perfectly and I get a full table of results in SQL Developer.

**I am attempting to do the same thing above in PHP using OCI. My code can be seen below:**

```
<?php

// Load up the system.
require('../../system/init.php');

global $config;

$oracleDb = oci_new_connect($config['oracleDb']['username'], $config['oracleDb']['password'], $config['oracleDb']['connectionString']);

$firstStid = oci_parse($oracleDb, "BEGIN PKG_KTY_SEARCH.PR_PRICE_LIST(); END;");
oci_execute($firstStid);

$secondStid = oci_parse($oracleDb, "SELECT * FROM kty_web.KTY_PROD_PRICE_TEMP");
oci_execute($secondStid);

oci_fetch_all($secondStid, $result);

echo json_encode($result);

echo "<br />Import complete!";

?>
```

This however returns no errors, and an empty result set. I can't figure out why. Anybody seeing anything obvious here that I'm missing?

**Result set returned from PHP**

```
{"PRODUCT_ID":[],"CUST_ROLE":[],"MIN_QTY":[],"MAX_QTY":[],"PRICE":[]}
```

**My connection string is as follows:**

```
$config['oracleDb']['connectionString'] = "(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = " . $config['oracleDb']['host'] . ")(PORT = " . $config['oracleDb']['port'] . ")))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=" . $config['oracleDb']['sid'] . ")))";
```

I am using **PHP7.1.22**, and **Oracle 11g** database. I am able to query normal tables and get results without problems within PHP and get a full result set.

Comment: Maybe this thread can be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41506335/call-oracle-stored-procedure-from-php

Comment: Thank you for passing this along, Eduardo. Will review with my DBA and get their feedback on this.

Comment: Although it sounds like a DB connection or privilege issue, you should still add some error checking in your code.  Review the [OCI8 manual error examples](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.oci-error.php).  Also review [The Underground PHP and Oracle Manual](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/php/underground-php-oracle-manual-098250.html).

Comment: Not related the to solution, but this may be useful: You are making two `oci_execute()` calls, which means at least two "round-trips" to the DB.  For performance and scalability, can you add the query to the first anonymous block and return a REF CURSOR with the query results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the temporary table defined as `on commit delete rows` or as `on commit preserve rows`?

By default, `oci_execute` will implicitly issue a `commit` after every successful call.  Assuming your temporary table is defined as `on commit delete rows`, that will delete the rows before the subsequent query.  You can change that behavior by passing an optional second parameter

```
oci_execute($firstStid, OCI_DEFAULT);
```

Assuming you do this, however, you'll want to do an explicit `oci_commit` in order to close the transaction you've opened.

Comment: This worked! Can't believe it was that simple. Thanks Justin! :)